# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib' on windows 10 using Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I want to build **dlib** on windows 10 by the following step:

`pip install dlib`

But I am getting an error

> > > import dlib
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'

I want to work with dlib for Eye tracking and recognition process.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: you are working on same environment right?

Comment: Yes I am working on same environment and by the downloaded file of dlib getting an error is **ERROR: dlib-19.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda try this:

```
conda install -c menpo dlib
```

Using pip can break your conda environment so try and avoid that in Anaconda.